# Hide complete text if it overflows

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have description text which i want to wrap and limit to only 2 lines. If the text overflows i want to hide the complete text not just the overflown part. How to do that?

```css
.description {
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae leo dapibus, accumsan lorem eleifend, pharetra quam. Quisque vestibulum commodo justo, eleifend mollis enim blandit eu. Aenean hendrerit nisl et elit maximus finibus. Suspendisse scelerisque consectetur nisl mollis scelerisque.
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to use javascript to hide the text if description height is greater than 20px, i have the solution.

Comment: yeah, you need javascript on that;

Comment: @hussain.codes css would be better but yeah i can checkout the js solution too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need javascript to get the height of `span` element. if it's greater than 20px than simply set span `display` property to `none`. I hope it helps

Below snippets will not render anything because span height is greater than 20px so it's not displayed

```js
const span = document.getElementsByClassName('description')[0];

// if height is greater than 20px then simply set display to none
if(parseInt(getComputedStyle(span).height)>20){
    span.style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
.description {
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae leo
    dapibus, accumsan lorem eleifend, pharetra quam. Quisque vestibulum commodo
    justo, eleifend mollis enim blandit eu. Aenean hendrerit nisl et elit
    maximus finibus. Suspendisse scelerisque consectetur nisl mollis
    scelerisque.
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript.

```
<script>
var elm=document.querySelector('.description').offsetHeight;
if(elm>20){
    document.querySelector('.description').style.display="none";
}
</script>
```